# Send text to Visual Studio Output in UWP

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, visual-studio-debugging, c++-cx

In standard .NET there's System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine, in UWP C# there's also System.Diagnostics.Debug - but when I write a C++/CX Windows Runtime Component there's apparently no assembly reference to System.Diagnostics.Debug...

Am I missing a reference or am I supposed to not be able to use this in VC++ Windows Runtime Components?

Do I need to wrap access to this as a separate C# Windows Runtime Component and then reference that runtime component in my C++ runtime component?

I must be missing something simple, but I'm generally new to VC++ with UWP and UWP in general.

Sorry, as of yet, documentation and resources on UWP are scarce.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OutputDebugString` to write debugging statements in C++.

Comment: Sigh... thanks... I tried that earlier in a destructor, but, being a WRC type the destructor wasn't running so I was getting no output at all.  I thought I had read the WRC destructors were guaranteed to run - but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: If you declare a destructor for a `ref` type, then it implicitly implements `ICloseable` and can be used in a `using` block in C#